# MISP Threat Indicators to Azure sentinel - Python Script issue

Tags: python, azure, azure-sentinel

I am trying to push the threat indicators from my MISP instance to azure sentinel by using azure's default documentation on github : https://github.com/microsoftgraph/security-api-solutions/tree/master/Samples/MISP

I performed the steps as per documentation however python3 script.py is giving me following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 100, in <module>
    main()
  File "script.py", line 96, in main
    request_manager.handle_indicator(request_body)
  File "/var/azure/sentinel/security-api-solutions/Samples/MISP/RequestManager.py", line 197, in handle_indicator
    self._post_to_graph()
  File "/var/azure/sentinel/security-api-solutions/Samples/MISP/RequestManager.py", line 184, in _post_to_graph
    self._log_post(response)
  File "/var/azure/sentinel/security-api-solutions/Samples/MISP/RequestManager.py", line 98, in _log_post
    if len(response['value']) > 0:
KeyError: 'value'
```

This is calling inbuilt method in RequestManager.py for posting the indicators to Graph API

Answer (score 1):

Don't know the answer to your Python questions but have you tried using the Threat Intelligence Platform connector directly against your app?  It is in public preview right now.

Comment: yes I have tried that and that it not working as well